# How to get qtserialport to work for NVIDIA TX1 for Native QT?

Tags: qt, native, nvidia, qtserialport

Hi I need the serial ports for my project.
I'm working with QT natively on my TX1.
I've been trying every tutorial I could find.

Is there any way I can get qtserialport to work?

please help,

Yohann Payet

Comment: Please post your code or the steps your followed until you encountered the problem

Comment: It goes bad right from the start. 
Empty project.
QT  += core gui serialport

I get this error:
Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport

It's qt5.5.1 on ubuntu 16.04

thanks

Comment: Did you try to add QT += serialport?

Comment: Hi,
Yes I did, I basically used the same script I used for the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Run these 2 lines (terminal):

sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5

sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5-dev

seems to do the job.

Have a nice day